# emscripten C++11 with boost support issue

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, webassembly, emscripten

[image]

I have an issue when building my C++ project that uses boost in Emscripten as shown on the screenshot, it says that '_Atomic' is a C11 extension however even if i add -std=c++11 or even -std=c11 i am still getting the error, the _Atomic use is defined from boost.

any idea on how to work around on this? reading around it does say that C++11 is already supported in Emscripten.

my setup.
compiler: emscripten/em++ Clang 12.0.8

Comment: Please post errors as text not screenshots

Comment: Why does your project specify multiple `-std=c++` flags? (Also C11 != C++11, they are different languages)

Comment: @UnholySheep I know, as i posted above, i also tried -std=c11 to same result, the screenshot is is using c++11, but i had explained in the post that i tried C11 as well.
the two -std is a desperation move coz nothing is working.

Comment: Well you screenshot shows that netio project is the one including emscripten, but it is not clear from which project the shown CMakeLists.txt comes from (if it is not netio, then changing it will not affect anything), also a good to add `-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON` to your cmake invocation to see that the  flag is actually present in the compiler invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why

The message in your screenshot shows:

- you are compiling with clang
- *error: '_Atomic' is a C11 extension [-Werror,**-Wc11-extensions**]*

So clang warns on c11 extensions because it has the diagnostic flag set, and is also configured to fail on warning which leads to your failed compilation.

- -Wc11-extensions may have been specified directly in your compilation commands
- or indirectly by -Wpedantic (see https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#id604)

## How to fix

You could specifically deactivate this warning with the **-Wno-c11-extensions** compiler flag, see this good explanation here on how to do it: https://nelkinda.com/blog/suppress-warnings-in-gcc-and-clang/